# Quantity button when null crashes windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I created a windows store app that has two buttons that will allow my users to select amounts of pictures. The control works when they need to pick the amount but when they click the 'X' inside of the textbox if they want to clear it out and then pressed a button the app crashes.

[image]

When I debug I get this error on my block of code:

`{"Input string was not in a correct format."}`

```
private void PicturesSubtract_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int? value = Convert.ToInt32(this.Pic.Text);

    if (value > 1)
    {
        value--;
    }


    this.Pic.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

I get the same error when trying to add or subtract the picture amount.

Any help on this error would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This line throws your error

```
int? value = Convert.ToInt32(this.Pic.Text);
```

The reason for this is that `Convert.ToInt32` assumes you have a valid integer, and throws an exception in EVERY other case, including null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

There are two options I would recommend

The first, null check your text value before doing anything else:

```
private void PicturesSubtract_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Pic.Text))
        return;
....
```

The second, use the Int.TryParse method:

```
private void PicturesSubtract_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int value;
    if(int.TryParse(this.Pic.Text, out value))
    {
        //...Do Stuff, Value is stored at this point
```

Comment: There may be other options as well, but those are the two I'm most familiar with.

Comment: Well, ok...maybe not EVERY other case...I think that will Truncate the value if its a valid number with a decimal point, I try never to use it that way myself.

Comment: Still getting the error after I check for the null value and then using tryParse.

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format" means that, quite literally.  If your input string is not null, and not an integer, then Convert will still throw that error.  As far as I am aware, TryParse will not throw that error.  If you are still receiving this message, AND are using int.TryParse, double check the source of the error, because it wont be in that code.